# NodeJS: function not returning res.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

So I am making a post api for registration/signup. If a user is successfully been registered, an access token will be provided to the user for saving it in frontend.
Everything works, the username, password is saving in database along with the token. But the access token is not returning. I have used mongoDB as my database and used mongoose. Here what I have done so far:
**Edited code**

```
const UserModel = require("../models/userModel");
var bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const registration = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    if (!(email && password)) {
      res.status(400).send("All input is required");
    }
    const existingEmail = await UserModel.find({ email: email });
    if (existingEmail.length === 0) {
      const userToken = jwt.sign({ email: email }, process.env.SECRET, {
        expiresIn: "90d",
      });

      let hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 8);
      const user = await UserModel.create({
        email,
        password: hashedPassword,
        token: userToken,
      });
      await userRegistration.save(function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
        } else {
          console.log(result);
        }
      });
      res.json(userToken);
    } else {
      res.json("email has already been registered");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    res.json(err);
  }
};

module.exports = registration;
```

if I test the api in thunder client on vscode, it is returning {}, an empty object. Please tell me what I have done wrong?

Comment: Maybe existingEmail.length != 0

Answer (score 0):

`const existingEmail = await UserModel.find({ email });` This line of yours will provide you the array of all the users because `email` property has nothing, it will be just like `.find({})`

If you are checking if the `email` inserted by user is already in your database or not, I suggest you do it like this: `const existingEmail = await UserModel.find({ email : email});`
This will return the document with `email` property's value equal to the email you received in `req.body` i.e. `email : xyz@gmail.com`

And In this line  `const userToken = jwt.sign({ email }, process.env.SECRET, {expiresIn: "90d",});`
You are again making same mistake. The object you pass in payload, has `email` property, but no value/email is assigned to that property.
It's just like `email : undefined`

Here, do it like this `jwt.sign({email : email}, process.env.SECRET, {expiresIn: '90d')})`

Comment: well thanks but still doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what has been mentioned in the other answers, to me it looks like you are not giving the token to `res.json` anywhere.

Your function is returning the token, but I dont think its going anywhere. You need to pass the token to res.json, not return from the function.

You are using `await` as well as `.then()` which looks wrong to me. You have to use just one of them.

**Update:**
`jwt.sign` returns a string so `userToken` contains string. You are giving that string to `res.json` which is expecting a json. You need to pass an object to it.

Comment: please brother see my edited code.

Comment: @tanjimanim `jwt.sign` returns a string so `userToken` contains string. You are giving that string to `res.json` which is expecting a json. You need to pass an object to it. If that doesnt work, you need to show us what is the response you are getting on postman or some other client.

Comment: it has been solved. I am getting the response now. thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, I made a simple mistake in the code. I was trying to save userRegistration which was not defined. That's why the bug was occurring. I should be more careful about this.

Answer (score -1):

Kindly try the below mentioned code.

```
const UserModel = require("../models/userModel");
var bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const registration = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    if (!(email && password)) {
      res.status(400).send("All input is required");
    }
    const existingEmail = await UserModel.find({ email });

   if (existingEmail.length === 0) {
     const userToken = jwt.sign({ email }, process.env.SECRET, {
       expiresIn: "90d",
     });

     let hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 8);
     const user = await UserModel.create({
       email,
       password: hashedPassword,
       token: userToken,
     });

     const userRegistrationResponse = await userRegistration.save();

     const responseObj = {
       ...userRegistrationResponse,
       accesstoken: `${userToken}`
     };
  
     res.json(responseObj);


     } else {
       res.json("email has already been registered");
     }
  } catch (err) {
    res.json(err);
  }
};

module.exports = registration;
```

Comment: this code doesn't work